# Unsampled data with Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to automate the weekly report. Currently, I am using Google Analytics website to get the data for my report. Sampling level is higher precision.

I tried to get the same data by Google analytics API set samplingLevel as HIGHER_PRECISION. However, I am still getting the sampled data.

For FASTER, Precision Level is roughly 25% whereas for DEFAULT and HIGHER_PRECISION sampling level is roughly 50%.

On Google Analytics website, it says 'This report is based on 100% of sessions'. Can I get the same level of accuracy with Google API? I am using Google Apps script.Response for HIGHER_PRECISION is not matching.

Comment: No the API has a different sampling threshold than the UI 1M vs 100M or something to that affect. You can always use the [unsampled reports API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports) though. You can also shorten the date range and assemble the results afterwards. IE request just one date and drop the `ga:date` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sumit, the API and the Google Analytics UI are certainly different and similarly the sampling's effect on things is a different beast which must be handled properly to get anything useful out of it.

As was mentioned in the comment, you can achieve high precision unsampled reports by (typically) shortening your date range that you're querying for and then "walking" the data.

To walk the data, you are essentially just gradually incrementing that small date range as you move through the desired data.

The "unsampled reports API" is... well, not the best. Considering that's what they are avoiding giving the end user in the first place, the offering available is not a very good long term or large project friendly solution. I would recommend small date ranges and then doing a data walk.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to avoid sampling issue in Google Analytics by automating the process of data export for short date ranges.

I prefer this tool, it's pretty simple to use: [MadStats.io](https://madstats.io/)